# Python - BeautifulSoup findParent by attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm hoping to use the findParent() method in BeautifulSoup to find a particular tag's parent that has an id attribute. For example, consider the following sample XML:

```xml
<monograph>
    <section id="1234">
        <head>Test Heading</head>
        <p>Here's a paragraph with some text in it.</p>
    </section>
</monograph>
```

Assuming I've matched something in the paragraph, I'd like to use findParent to indiscriminately find the first parent up the tree with an id attribute. Something like:

```
 for hit in monograph(text="paragraph with"):
     containername = hit.findParent(re.compile([A-Za-z]+), {id}).name
```

However, the preceding code doesn't return any hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `id=True` to match an element that has an `id` attribute, regardless of the value of the attribute:

```
hit.find_parent(id=True)
```

Inversely, using `id=False` would find the first parent element *without* an `id` attribute.

Note that you should really use the *lower_case_with_underscores* style for BeautifulSoup methods; `findParent` is the BeautifulSoup 3 spelling that [has been deprecated](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4).

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> sample = '''\
... <monograph>
...     <section id="1234">
...         <head>Test Heading</head>
...         <p>Here's a paragraph with some text in it.</p>
...     </section>
... </monograph>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, 'xml')
>>> str(soup.p)
"<p>Here's a paragraph with some text in it.</p>"
>>> print(soup.p.find_parent(id=True).prettify())
<section id="1234">
 <head>
  Test Heading
 </head>
 <p>
  Here's a paragraph with some text in it.
 </p>
</section>

>>> print(soup.p.find_parent(id=False).prettify())
<monograph>
 <section id="1234">
  <head>
   Test Heading
  </head>
  <p>
   Here's a paragraph with some text in it.
  </p>
 </section>
</monograph>
```